# Referencing a hashed svg from the html (webpack)

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack

I'm using file-loader to hash my svg spritesheet to `./dist/svg/sprite.e3452.svg`

```
{
    test: /\.(svg)$/,
    use: {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[name].[hash:5].[ext]',
            outputPath: './svg/'
        }
    }
}
```

It might be a simple question, but how can I reference an svg file from the html when the name changes with the hash?

For example here:

```
<svg class="close__icon">
    <use xlink:href="svg/sprite.svg#ios-trash-outline"></use>
</svg>
```

I use HtmlWebpackPlugin for similar problems with my hashed js files, but can't find anything similar for my svgs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved or not but I just had same problem and here the solution.
Webpack insert the sprite svg in the dom and you can access each id with an underscore after the id of the sprite, in your case:

```
<svg class="close__icon">
    <use xlink:href="#sprite_ios-trash-outline"></use>
</svg>
```